# Cannot create temporary file - mkstemp: No such file or directory

Tags: mkstemp

In centos when installing package `yum install <package>` 
it didn't work & throws the error as  `Cannot create temporary file - mkstemp: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 4):

May be you could have deleted your `/tmp` directory
`mkdir -p /tmp/mkstempc` resolves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.

Discovered that my environment variable TMP was set to ~/tmp .  As root, dnf didn't like that.  so I

```
$ unset TMP
```

Then (CentOS stream 8)
`'dnf install <package>'`
worked fine.

For more background, a similar question was asked, but no specific resolution:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1030768/linux-error-creating-temporary-file-var-tmp

Comment: Could also be a full /tmp directory.  In that case, Check /tmp for anything which could be removed.

Here is some more background information:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277387/tab-completion-errors-bash-cannot-create-temp-file-for-here-document-no-space

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have deleted /tmp directory

Create /tmp directory again

sudo mkdir /tmp

For termux
mkdir /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp